How to reference an external javascript method with javascript without using html?
Currently, I'm working on a project that (for organization reasons) needs to have a few different javascript files and I don't know how to reference a javascript file externally. I'm making a discord bot, so I don't know if there is a way to access the html document while the bot is running to access the doc. these are located in the same file
app.js
const { Client, IntentsBitField } = require('discord.js');
const token = "token_here";
import {sendMessage} from './test.js';

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMembers,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.MessageContent
    ]
});

client.on('ready', (clientTemp) => {
    console.log(`${clientTemp.user.tag} is online`);
});

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    //if (message.content === 'say ping') {
    //    message.channel.send('!ping');
    //}

    //if (message.content == 'pong!') {
    //    message.channel.send('Message Received');
    //}
    sendMessage(message);
})

client.login(token);

test.js
export function sendMessage(message) {
    if (message.content === 'say ping') {
        message.channel.send('!ping');
    }
}

I've tried using the module way of setting the function to export then sending the main script to import that function, but the error comes up with "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" and then immediately shuts down. I'm still fairly new to javascript and have been toying around with what I can use. Is there a work around? I'm used to c# with namespaces and classes so this is a different syntax for me.
My first attempt was shown above with what I was trying to do. Second attempt was chaning
import { sendMessage } from './test.js';
to
import { sendMessage } from 'test.js';
with the same results.

access the html document while the bot is running - so this is running in a browser?

Sorry, I should have clarified. What I'm finding is online uses html to set a global script. I'm more wondering if there is a way to do it without html. It's not meant to run on the browser.

OK, so this is node? Have you set your project to use modules?

first you want to export the function:


const sendMessage = (message) => {
    if (message.content === 'say ping') {
        message.channel.send('!ping');
    }
}

module.exports = {
  sendMessage,
  //other functions
}



then you can either acces it at the top:
const { sendMessage } = require("path-to-file")

or at the place you are handling the event:
require("path-to-file").sendMessage(message)

if the main code is placed at project folder and the other file is placed at project/handlers folder, you will write "./handlers/FILENAME" there should be no .js at the end
